# want to render an array (not hard coded) on a line chart

Tags: highcharts

I want to render a histogram/line chart using HighCharts.
I don't want to hard code the array which is used by series. 
My data that I wish to render is in the object display, which looks like:

0: o, 107983,
1: 1, 347923,
2: 2, 182329,
.
.
.

My code is here:

```
function RenderChart(display) {
    myDisplay = display;

    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'line'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Metric histogram'
        },
        xAxis: {
            //categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            minPadding: 0.05,
            maxPadding: 0.05
        },
        plotOptions: {
            line: {
                animation: false
            },
            column: {
                groupPadding: 0,
                pointPadding: 0,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [myDisplay]
        }]

    });
};
```

This doesn't render the line chart. It renders an empty chart.

Comment: Can you explain the data/the object display a little bit? What does the first and second number represent?

Comment: I don't know what an `object display` is?  Is it part of the webpage's DOM?

Comment: The display object is a Json object that which is the output of another function. So Im calling 
public ActionResult GetDataFromStream(string streamName) which return the json object, which I want to render on the histogram.

Comment: My basic problem is that I don't want to hardcode data. If I use 
data: [[10,100], [20, 200], [25, 300]] this renders fine. But I can't hard code data.

Comment: Ethan: The first and second number represent the key and value.

Comment: What is the difference if you use hardcoded values or viaraible array? It is the same strucutre as a result, so if it doens;t work correct, probably array is not prepared fine.

Answer (score -1):

run a routine such that the response you get is processed as accepted by the highchart. then you can assign the resultant to the data directly.

try this, it will work

Comment: What did you want me to try?

Comment: I think what you need to do is, change {0: 0, 107983, 1: 1, 347923, 2: 2, 182329, . . .} -> [[0, 107983], [1, 347923], [2, 182329]...]

Comment: Yea. I tried to stringify my array and then Json.parse it. But that doesn't work either.

Comment: Right now, I have an array in which I am trying to push sub arrays. I don't know what is another way of doing it.

Comment: you try to push data in this order 0: 107983, 1:  347923, 2: 182329... this should work